# How to draw Parallel Line in android

Tags: android

I want to draw a parallel line in android. If i know the both the points of first line and knows the one point of the second line, so how can I draw a parallel line. I am using the OnTouchEvent() Method. If I draw a line and after that I touch any point in the screen than this line should be show as a parallel line of the first line.

Answer (score 1):

Remember y=m*x+b?  You calculate the slope (m) of the first line.  Then you calculate what b would have to be for the second line to have the same slope (parallel lines have the same slope).  Then you pick another point on the second line by choosing an x value and calculating the y for it.

Comment: suppose I got this equation, y=0.022206929x+112.255039. From this equation i can find out the b. So now how can i found the second point for second line.

Comment: Pick any x and plug it in.  Solve for the y.  Any value of x is valid.

Comment: And If I touch the finger in the screen for the second point. Then how can I draw the parallel line?